# How can start I tunning mobile flex application in flex4.5 using FlashBuilder 4.5?

Tags: performance, apache-flex, flex4.5, flash-builder4.5

I am working on tunning (performance) a Flex mobile application. How
can I start tunning the application in flex 4.5 using flash builder4.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several tips you can find on the following article

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex-mobile-performance-checklist.html

these will help you make your application faster.

basicaly the best thing to do is keep it simple, use spark components and use ActionScript renders rather than mxml to improve performance.